# unable to compile code when using useValue in Provider

Tags: angular6

The code is available at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xesgxe

It is a signup form and I am trying to create a custom validator. The validation functions are in `helper.service.ts`. I want to validate the `verify password` field in a different way and have created `validateVerifyPassword` function in `helper.service.ts`. While all the other fields are being validated using `Validators....` functions in `signup-component.components.ts`, I want to validate the `verify password` field using a custom directive in `signup-component.component.html`.

other fields

```
lastName:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/[A-Za-z]+/)]], 
email:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.EMAIL_PATTERN)]],       
password:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8),this.helper.validatePassword]]
```

confirm password field

```
<input id="verify-password" type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="confirmPassword" [ngClass]="validateField('confirmPassword')" ngModel validateVerifyPassword >
```

But the code doesn't compile when I  add `providers` in `validate-verify-password.directive.ts`.

```
providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useValue:validateVerifyPassword, multi: true }
  ]
```

What am I doing wrong? The error is 
`Error in src/app/validate-verify-password.directive.ts (8:39)`
`validateVerifyPassword is not defined`
`Evaluating src/app/validate-verify-password.directive.ts`
`Evaluating src/app/app.module.ts`
`Evaluating src/main.ts`
`Booting application`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. I had defined `validateVerifyPassword` in `HelperService` class in `helper.service.ts` i.e.

```
export class HelperService {
validateVerifyPassword() {
}
}
```

I should have defined it as a function outside the class

```
export class HelperService {
}
function validateVerifyPassword() {
}
```